# Wordpress site "Loaded over https but requested an insecure stylesheet" in reference to google fonts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently, my Wordpress site went https, but now this is causing Google Fonts to be blocked. After reading around, I gather I need to remove the "http" from the "http://" with the Google font API code. However... I can not find it anywhere. I've looked in function.php, header.php and the CSS stylesheet. Tried using the inspector, but to no avail.

I know next to nothing about this kind of thing, so forgive me for sounding totally clueless. Any help would be *wonderful*.

The site: https://annasportfolio.com/

Comment: I suggest searching for the text fonts.googleapis.com in your theme's source code.

Comment: It's probably some plugin that's adding it.

Answer (score 0):

your site source has the line
    `<link rel='stylesheet' id='googleFonts-css'  ...>`
so take off the "-css" from the id and you'll have the handle for that style: "googleFonts". You can then try to use wp_dequeue_style in your functions.php to get rid of it.

```
function remove_styles_example() {
 wp_dequeue_style( 'googleFonts' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'remove_styles_example', 100 );
```

then replace it with your own

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'myGoogleFonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat', array(), '4.9.1', 'all' );
```

refs: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Answer (score 0):

I'v installed [SSL Insecure Content Fixed](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) and had to select **HTTP_CF_VISITOR (Cloudflare Flexible SSL); deprecated, since Cloudflare sends HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO** now since I'm using Cloudflare.